# box2d vertical edge or wall collision detection

Tags: libgdx, box2d, collision-detection

I am experimenting with collision detection using Box2d Between a ball and four walls of a rectangular block which I call the gameBed.

I am using the below code to setup the ball and the LeftEdge(left wall in this case) Bodies. For brevity I am giving the code only for the left wall.

```
  b2World = new World(new Vector2(0, 0), false);
  World.setVelocityThreshold(0);
  GameBed gameBed = levelManager.retGameBed();   // rectangular block 
  Vector2 origin = new Vector2();

  BodyDef leftWallDef = new BodyDef();
  leftWallDef.type = BodyType.StaticBody;
  leftWallDef.position.set(gameBed.position); // gameBed.position is the world co-ordinate of the bottom left corner of the rectangular block
  Body body = b2World.createBody(leftWallDef);
    PolygonShape leftWallShape = new PolygonShape();
    origin.x = 0.005f;
    origin.y = (float)(gameBed.bounds.getHeight()) / 2;
    float widthOfLeftWall = BallsMania_Constants.VIEWPORT_WIDTH/(2 * Gdx.graphics.getWidth());
    Gdx.app.log(TAG, "Width of Left Wall is " + widthOfLeftWall);
    leftWallShape.setAsBox(.1f, 
            gameBed.bounds.height/2, origin, 0); // setting the half of width to .1f so that it represents an edge. The height of the edge should be as long as the rectangular edge.
    FixtureDef leftWallFixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    leftWallFixtureDef.shape = leftWallShape;
    leftWallFixtureDef.restitution = 0.9f;
    body.createFixture(leftWallFixtureDef);

    leftWallShape.dispose();

  // Defining shape and fixture for ball
          Ball ball = new Ball();
     BodyDef ballBodyDef = new BodyDef();
     ballBodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
     ballBodyDef.position.set(ball.position);
     ballBodyDef.linearDamping = 0.4f;
     ball.body = b2World.createBody(ballBodyDef);
     CircleShape ballShape = new CircleShape();
     ballShape.setPosition(new Vector2(0, -1 * (float)(BallsMania_Constants.VIEWPORT_HEIGHT/2.0 
           - BallsMania_Constants.bottomBaseDelta 
           + ball.dimension.x/2)));
     ballShape.setRadius(ball.dimension.x/2);
     FixtureDef ballBodyFixture = new FixtureDef();
     ballBodyFixture.shape = ballShape;
     ballBodyFixture.friction = 0.5f;
     ballBodyFixture.restitution = 0.5f;
     ball.body.createFixture(ballBodyFixture);
     ballShape.dispose();
```

Problem:
The ball doesn't collide with the leftedge; it just permiates through it and doesn't bounce.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your left wall body and ball's body visible. Can you take a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The problem was that I was setting the positions of the Box2d bodies at two places, 

First:
    
leftWallDef.position.set(gameBed.position); 

Second:

    leftWallShape.setAsBox(.1f, gameBed.bounds.height/2, origin, 0); 

This is incorrect, the body must be set only using the second method. Once I removed the first postion I could see the leftedge and the ball started bouncing on contact.